# How to find the the port number allocated to the web service?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I have a Endpoint of the web service ex: https://192.168.1.200:8080/ab/cd. when I enter the URL its not working but when I remove the port number and try the same url Its Working. Am confused. Now How I check the port number that is assigned to it? Do I need to check IIS? Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Default HTTPS connection are going through port 443. And that is what your browser is trying when you remove the port number from your URL.

You can check the port number for your site in IIS: Click on your site, and in actions pane under Browse Website it is showing you the URL and the port number.

[image: ISS Action pane]